# How can I use HashSet instead of List iterating a collection on the MVC's View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, collections, view

I were using a `List<>` iterating some collection I have in my `ASP.NET MVC` Model. This is the `View`:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Accessories.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Accessories[i])
}
```

Which iterate this template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label(Model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-6 checkbox">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RegistrationId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Description)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Enabled)
    </div>
</div>
```

Having this `m.Enabled Hint` template:

```
@(Html.Kendo().RadioButtonFor(m => m).Label("Yes").Value(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "rb-observable" }))
@(Html.Kendo().RadioButtonFor(m => m).Label("No").Value(false).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "rb-observable" }))
```

The problem! For some reason, I've needed to change the `Accessories` collection type from:

```
Accessories = new List<Accessories>();
```

To:

```
Accessories = new HashSet<Accessories>();
```

(Due to how EntityFramework natively treat tables; it uses `HashSet` instead of `List`).
Now, I can't use @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Accessories[i]), since its not indexable.
And now the View mess the whole radio buttons/id/naming for the inputs.

How can I fix/translate it?

Comment: I believe you can use the **ToList** extension. You need to add System.Linq and then: **Accessories.ToList()[i]**

Answer (score 1):

The `EditorFor()` methods accepts `IEnumerable<T>` as the model and correctly generates the correct html for each item it the collection based on the `EditorTemplate`.

Do not generate the html within a loop. It simply needs to be

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Accessories)
```

Having said that, it should be irrelevant that you data model collection is `HashSet`. Your editing data so you should always be using view model, not your data model - refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc).